# MongoDB - too much data for sort() with no index. Full collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using Mongoose for Node.js to interface with the mongo driver, so my query looks like:

```
db.Deal
    .find({})
    .select({
        _id: 1,
        name: 1,
        opp: 1,
        dateUploaded: 1,
        status: 1
     })
     .sort({ dateUploaded: -1 })
```

And get: **too much data for sort() with no index. add an index or specify a smaller limit**

The number of documents in the `Deal` collection is quite small, maybe ~500 - but each one contains many embedded documents. The fields returned in the query above are all primitive, i.e. aren't documents.

I currently don't have any indexes setup other than the default ones - I've never had any issue until now. Should I try adding a compound key on:

`{ _id: 1, name: 1, opp: 1, status: 1, dateUploaded: -1 }`

Or is there a smarter way to perform the query? First time using mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MongoDB documentation on [limits and thresholds](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#limit-sort):

> MongoDB will only return sorted results on fields without an index if the combined size of all documents in the sort operation, plus a small overhead, is less than 32 megabytes.

Probably all the embedded documents are too much, you should add an index on the sorted field `dateUploaded` if you want to run the same query.

Otherwise you can limit you query and start paginating the results.

Comment: so just add a single index on `dateUploaded`?

Comment: @Kat yeah try that. Indexing the field that you are using for sorting your documents should do the job.